# In Standard ML, how can you catch an exception like "Error: unbound variable or constructor: foo"?

Tags: sml, ml

I have this newbie question: in Standard ML, how can you catch an exception like "Error: unbound variable or constructor: foo"?

I tried to do this with the following program:

```
(foo())
handle Error msg => ();
```

But REPL complains: "Error: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern: Error"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it's `handle Error => ...` (or `handle error => ...` or `handle TheSpecificExceptionIWantToCatch => ...`), not `handle Error msg => ...`. You can only write `handle Foo msg => ...` if `Foo` is a constructor with one argument, which, as the error message suggests, `Error` is not.

Secondly "unbound variable" is a compilation error, not an exception, so it can't be caught.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the existing answer. I noticed Chao tried to "catch" an Error based on the message it received trying to execute the code. A genuine exception message in the REPL is reported right after the line `val it = () : unit`, indicating it happens after the interpretation phase. Furthermore, in the Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 interpreter, it appears at execution time with a message like:

`uncaught exception ExceptionName
  raised at: filename.sml:linei.columni-linej.columnj`

So not seeing an explicit message along these lines should *raise* the alarm that no exception has been raised, no pun intended.
Since the question was how to catch an exception not an error, I think the mechanism for an exception has to be briefly explained:

1. Somewhere in the code, within the lexical scope of where it will be used, an exception binding has to be defined:
   `exception MyException` or `exception MyException2 of String`
2. Somewhere in an expression a case is found that merits the interruption of normal control flow and thus uses the following primitive to do just that:
   `raise MyException` or `raise (MyException2("Error in foo"))`
3. The exceptional interruption of flow can be caught with a handle expression that uses pattern matching on the exception constructor and submits and alternative expression for evaluation. In this case expression `e1` raises the exception and the handler returns expression e2: `e1 handle MyException => e2`

For more details on how to write clean and elegant exception handlers for complex functions, with recovery of execution if so desired, read this page of the on-line notes [Programming in Standard ML by Robert Harper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/core/exceptions.htm)